# Add ability to hide job postings on/from careers.stackoverflow?

Tags: feature-request

I've had a couple of job postings that show up as relevant to me that I would prefer to not see in the Careers widget (the postings don't require flagging, but I don't need to see job postings for them).

I think it'd be good to have an option to hide these postings on a posting or company level, to allow other postings show in the relevant section, or at the very least, on the widget.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand why this matters one way or the other. Can't you just ignore such postings? Seriously - I'm not trying to be flippant, but really don't understand - can you say more about why or how this is an issue, for what reasons would you "prefer to not see [them]" ?

Comment: @HowardPautz - One particular case is that it's a company I already have a relationship with. I have no need to see their postings, let alone always have them in the three that display on every StackOverflow page. I've had others where I looked at them and wasn't really qualified for them, but it still shows up in the widget. Sure, I can mentally ignore them, but having useless posting in the widget all the time renders the widget irrelevant.

Comment: Then I'd think just "mentally ignoring it" seems the easiest thing to do. Aren't we used to that already? Most of us phase out Google ads, etc. Seems like it would add more overhead to the system than what it gains. Besides, if you really are looking for other work, clearly there are other more effective means of doing so - the job postings in question are really just a convenience. Still in consideration of your question, perhaps another alternative might be to have a "show more listings" button that would refresh with other, new ones ?

Comment: @HowardPautz Then why have the widget at all? By your logic, I might as well just set AdBlock to remove it. While I may not be actively looking at the moment that I'm visiting an SO page, I may be open to opportunities, and therefore open to what the widget has to offer. Frankly, the widget itself often catches my eye, but then I see it's the same three postings. A "refresh" button seems kind of half-assed to me, as it doesn't address the underlying problem of "I don't want this one in the rotation at all."

Comment: I literally just thought of making this request and then found this post. Whenever searching for a job, I keep seeing the same ones I don't want to apply to over and over. In actively searching and filtering these posts, it doesn't make sense to "mentally ignore" 20 out of 25 posts, and is a poor pattern.

Comment: @shauna "just set ad block to remove it ... 'refresh' seems half-assed"   Hmmm ... Well, Yes, I'm beginning to see your (and @ asifrc's) point. I wonder how many ads (on average) are actually in there "rotating" you think ? ( I'm sure the SE folks know, but probably wouldn't tell us :-P )  So if we had, say, a check box next to the ads (i.e. check means 'hide') would that work for you all ?  Still, I'll bet there are implications - it might violate terms the SE owners have with their advertisers. And there still is that problem of system overhead of adding more customizations for each user.

Comment: @HowardPautz - There's already overhead in filtering for things that are relevant, so the added overhead of "and not hidden" should be rather small, depending (of course) on how they do the filtering to begin with. As for terms SE owners have with employers, well...that's something only they can answer.

Comment: I would also appreciate the ability to filter out uninteresting jobs and postings for which I am under-qualified.